# JS dataTables.fixedHeader different width between header and datas

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, fixed-header-tables

I use the javascript plugin dataTables.fixedHeader and fill the data with ajax.
Now I have the problem, that the width of each data-column is dynamically and the header stays on the same static width.

[image: Different width]

Code:

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="custTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                ......
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                ......
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                ......
                            </th>
......
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="dataList"></tbody>
                </table>
```

JS:

```
table = $('#custTable').DataTable({
            "dom": "frtiS",
            "deferRender": true,
        });
```

Fill it:

```
$('#custTable').dataTable().fnAddData([
               xyz, xyz, xyz, ...
                        ]);
```

Comment: Can you provide more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable automatic column widths.

**JS**

```
table = $('#custTable').DataTable({
            "dom": "frtiS",
            "deferRender": true,
            "autoWidth": false
        });
```

http://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth